# Use google player to play non google urls

Tags: html, video, embed

I remember seeing someone using the google player to play non-google videos. Does anyone know how to do this? For example I have on my site http://www.mysite.com/vid.wmv , how can I get that to play on google's embedded player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can embed a video but you can use the google player to play your own audio
http://www.labnol.org/internet/design/html-embed-mp3-songs-podcasts-music-in-blogs-websites/2232/